# MySql Script update on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update, alter-table

I have trouble to put MySQL query to php Codeigniter. I try to search but I haven't found yet.

this is the code :

```
UPDATE `Pelayanan` SET `TGLBAYAR` = INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 3, 0, '/'), INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 6, 0, '/')
UPDATE `Pelayanan` SET `TGLRUBAH` = INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 3, 0, '/'), INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 6, 0, '/')
ALTER TABLE `Pelayanan` MODIFY COLUMN (`TGLBAYAR` DATE, `TGLRUBAH` DATE)

UPDATE `Pelayanan` SET `LAMA` = DATEDIFF(`TGLBAYAR`, `TGLRUBAH`)
```

I want to run this code in sequence but I don't know whether to use CASE or something.
How is the code for controller.php and model.php?

Comment: can u describe a little bit more

Comment: Are those valid queries? Do you get any errors if you run these queries directly in the MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

What is the

> INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 3, 0, '/'), INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 6, 0, '/')

Can you change it to be string? If can, on Your Model **add this function** and **call it** from **controller**

```
 public function update_data(){
     $fields = array(
           'TGLBAYAR' => "INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 3, 0, '/'), INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 6, 0, '/')",
           'TGLRUBAH' => "INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 3, 0, '/'), INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 6, 0, '/')"
        );
     $this->db->update('Pelayanan', $fields, array());

     $fields = array(
          'TGLBAYAR' => array(
               'name' => 'TGLBAYAR',
               'type' => 'DATE',
          ),
          'TGLRUBAH' => array(
               'name' => 'TGLRUBAH',
               'type' => 'DATE',
          ),
      );
      $this->db->modify_column('Pelayanan', $fields);

     $fields = array(
           'LAMA' => "DATEDIFF(`TGLBAYAR`, `TGLRUBAH`)"
        );
     $this->db->update('Pelayanan', $fields, array());

 }
```

Comment: TGLBAYAR is already in String

I have run this code but still error :
"Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::modify_column()"

Comment: @user1213 What CI version do you using? try to refer to this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html

Comment: Thanks.
I use Codeigniter 3.0.0. I think I should migrate database to fix the error

Comment: Hi can i see your controller @user1213

Answer (score 0):

the alter table section should be the followig:

```
$this->load->dbforge();

 $fields = array(
          'TGLBAYAR' => array(
               'name' => 'TGLBAYAR',
               'type' => 'DATE',
          ),
          'TGLRUBAH' => array(
               'name' => 'TGLRUBAH',
               'type' => 'DATE',
          ),
      );
 $this->dbforge->modify_column('Pelayanan', $fields);
```

Also, if you have any error message please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your query is, just put it in the function $this->db->query and it will be executed very easily and you can understand it properly as you want. I have put a sample for your mysql query below:

```
$query = $this->db->query(" UPDATE `Pelayanan` SET `TGLBAYAR` = 
INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 3, 0, '/'), INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 6, 0, '/')
UPDATE `Pelayanan` SET `TGLRUBAH` = INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 3, 0, '/'), 
INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 6, 0, '/') ALTER TABLE `Pelayanan` MODIFY COLUMN 
(`TGLBAYAR` DATE, `TGLRUBAH` DATE) UPDATE `Pelayanan` SET `LAMA` = 
DATEDIFF(`TGLBAYAR`, `TGLRUBAH`) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->set('TGLBAYAR', "INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 3, 0, '/')", FALSE);
$this->db->set('TGLBAYAR', "INSERT(`TGLBAYAR`, 6, 0, '/')", FALSE);
$this->db->set('TGLRUBAH', "INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 3, 0, '/')", FALSE);
$this->db->set('TGLRUBAH', "INSERT(`TGLRUBAH`, 6, 0, '/')", FALSE);
$this->db->update('Pelayanan');
```

The Above code will replace `/` into `TGLBAYAR` and `TGLRUBAH` columns. And looking forward to alter a table you can use [Codeigniter Migrations](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html). It will be the best practice and more flexible when you go to Live deployment.

```
$fields = array(
        'TGLBAYAR' => array(
                'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
        'TGLRUBAH' => array(
                'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
);
$this->dbforge->modify_column('Pelayanan', $fields);
```

**Ref:** https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html#modifying-a-column-in-a-table

And then,

```
$this->db->set('LAMA', "DATEDIFF(`TGLBAYAR`, `TGLRUBAH`)", FALSE);
$this->db->update('Pelayanan');
```

Try this code and let me know if any errors occurred. Happy coding.